# What is abstract attribute in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class

What's the purpose to define a `Django` model with `abstract = True` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abstract=True` means this model is an abstract model class. It does not have a database table and is merely a shared parent model class so that the child models don't need to rewrite all the fields. Each child models will have their own table.

`abstract=False` means a normal model, django will create a table for it.